# Docker compose network issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    result:
        image: result
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        networks:
            - test-wp-network
```

And network:

```
docker network list  | grep test
a18a8c7a2764   test-wp-network   bridge    local
```

But when I run docker-compose up the following error is shown:

```
service "db" refers to undefined network test-wp-network: invalid compose project
```

Could you please clarify what is the issue and how it can be fixed?

For example, if I run it as below:

```
docker run --name=db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword --network=test-wp-network postgres:9.4
```

It is workin fine

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare networks before you use it in services.

see [Specify custom networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks) and [Use a pre-existing network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network) from `docker` manuals.

here is a sample config

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
    result:
        image: result
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        networks:
            - test-wp-network
networks:
  test-wp-network:
    external:
      name: "test-wp-network"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this compose file change image and tag

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8086:8086'
    network_mode: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

As you do have the network exist, Docker-compose will create a new network for any application you ran. beside what you already have.

This network will be accessible for all the services inside your application, and not accessible for other services inside other docker applications.

In case you need to share the access for this network, you have to define external network, usually at the end of the `docker-compose.yaml` like the following :

```
networks:
  test-wp-network:
    external:
      name: "test-wp-network"
```